# Graph Walking and Searching System in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, open-source, graph-theory

I am wondering whether there is a standard open-source graph-walking and graph-searching utility that is used in Common Lisp world. We have a need for a utility/system that would be able to deal (search, walk, find paths, etc) with multi-graphs. If needed, we could make it open-source, but we certainly do not want to re-invent the wheel if one already exists.

Answer (score 2):

There is `clml.graph` in [clml](http://mmaul.github.io/clml), which might do some of the things you need.  A quicklisp search `(ql:system-apropos "graph")` yields a managable number of more candidates to look at.

Other than that, there is of course Allegro Graph from Franz, which is a complete graph database.  If you can stand all the marketing lingo.

Comment: Do you know whether Allegro Graph is deployable? That is, I thought it requires licensing

Comment: Up to 5 million triples it's free: https://franz.com/agraph/allegrograph/ag_commercial_edition.lhtml